# Pandas Create Column with Groupby and Sum with additional condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a new column in pandas DataFrame after grouping and with additional conditions

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'A'  :[4,5,7,8,2,3,5,2,1,1,4,4,2,4,5,1,3,9,7,9], 
    'B'  :[9,5,7,8,3,3,5,2,1,1,4,4,2,4,5,1,3,5,7,9], 
    'C' :[9,5,7,8,3,3,5,2,1,1,4,4,2,4,5,1,3,5,7,9], 
    'D' :[1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0] 
})
df1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).transform('sum')
df1 = df.join(df.groupby(['A'])['C'].sum(), on='A', rsuffix='_inward')

df1
```

In above query it is able to sum and give output but how do I add condition for `df['D'] == 1`

Expected output

```
    A  B  C  D  C_inward
0   4  9  9  1        13
2   7  7  7  1        14
4   2  3  3  1         3
5   3  3  3  1         3
8   1  1  1  1         3
9   1  1  1  1         3
13  4  4  4  1        13
14  5  5  5  1        5
15  1  1  1  1         3
18  7  7  7  1        14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = df['D'] == 1
df1 = df[mask].join(df[mask].groupby(['A'])['C'].sum(), on='A', rsuffix='_inward')

print (df1)
    A  B  C  D  C_inward
0   4  9  9  1        13
2   7  7  7  1        14
4   2  3  3  1         3
5   3  3  3  1         3
8   1  1  1  1         3
9   1  1  1  1         3
13  4  4  4  1        13
14  5  5  5  1         5
15  1  1  1  1         3
18  7  7  7  1        14
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand question very well. If answer is wrong, please add desired output. Thanks.

Comment: Added expected output